# How to configure nginx to fix CORS errors?

Tags: nginx, web, nginx-config

So, I have backend app with address localhost:portX and frontend app with localhost:portY. How to balance nginx with this ports and fix CORS errors?

I try this, but it's not working

```
http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass_header Client;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_pass http://localhost:25900/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}
```